# How do I zip keys with individual values in my lists in python?

Tags: python, key, dictionary

I am importing a matrix, turning the first row into keys, and turning the rest of the rows into values.  I want to zip the keys with each value and put them in a dictionary.

ex:

If I have the following:

```
k = ['a', 'b']
v = [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

I want to take each value in v (for x in v) and zip them (k and x) then convert to a dictionary.

Then I will add the dictionaries to a list of dictionaries.

At the end I should have:

```
dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'b':4}]
```

Right now, I am only zipping my rows with my keys.  How do I fix this?

```
matrix_filename = raw_input("Enter the matrix filename:  ")  
matrix = [i.strip().split() for i in open(matrix_filename).readlines()]  
keys = matrix[0]  
vals= (matrix[1:])  
N=len(vals)  

dicts = []  

for i in range(1,N):  
    for j in range(1,N):  
        vals[i-1][j-1] = int(matrix[i][j])  
        dicts = dict(zip(keys,vals))
```

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> [dict(zip(k, x)) for x in v]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
```

Comment: +1 You just got it in one line, what took me a nested for loop. :(

Comment: Don't you love how easy it is to do in Python once you know your tools?

Answer (score 3):

using `itertools.cycle()`:

```
In [51]: from itertools import *

In [52]: cyc=cycle(k)

In [53]: [{next(cyc):y for y in x} for x in v]
Out[53]: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a generator-based solution, based on [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930762/11121534) from another question.

(duplicate of answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69578838/11121534)

This might be helpful when the dict is huge.

```
def zip_dict(d):
    for vals in zip(*(d.values())):
        yield dict(zip(d.keys(), vals))
```

Example usage:

```
d = dict(
    x=[1,3,5,7,9],
    y=[2,4,6,8,10]
)

for t in zip_dict(d):
    print(t)
```

The result would be:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
{'x': 3, 'y': 4}
{'x': 5, 'y': 6}
{'x': 7, 'y': 8}
{'x': 9, 'y': 10}
```