# 'Zip' dictionary of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists, and I want to merge them into a single list of namedtuples. I want the first element of all the lists in the first tuple, the second in the second and so on.

Example:

```
{'key1': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [4, 5, 6], 'key3': [7, 8, 9]}
```

And I want the resulting list to be like this:

```
[('key1': 1, 'key2': 4, 'key3': 7), 
('key1': 2, 'key2': 5, 'key3': 8), 
('key1': 3, 'key2': 6, 'key3': 9)]
```

I assume there is an elegant way of doing this?

**Edit:**

I have compared running times of @Steve Jessop's namedtuple answer to the dictionary version by @Ashwini Chaudhary, and the former is somewhat faster:

```
d = {key: numpy.random.random_integers(0, 10000, 100000) 
        for key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']}
```

Avg. of 100 runs:

```
namedtuple and map: 0.093583753109
namedtuple and zip: 0.119455988407
dictionary and zip: 0.159063346386
```

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted data structures. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Updated the question to be more precise. Haven't really tried anything yet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get the keys. You could sort them or whatever you like at this stage. Maybe you know what keys to use in what order, so you don't need to examine the data.

```
keys = list(d.keys())
```

Define the named tuple:

```
Record = collections.namedtuple('Record', keys)
```

Iterate all the lists in parallel:

```
[Record(*t) for t in zip(*(d[k] for k in keys))]
```

or `list(map(Record, *(d[k] for k in keys)))` if you like `map`.

Note that if `keys` is just `list(d.keys())` then you can use `d.values()` in place of `(d[k] for k in keys)`, because even though the order of keys in the dictionary is arbitrary it's guaranteed to be the same as the order of values. So if you don't care about the order of the fields in the namedtuple then it simplifies to:

```
Record = collections.namedtuple('Record', d.keys())
[Record(*t) for t in zip(*(d.values()))]
```

or `list(map(Record, *d.values()))` if you like `map`.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> d = {'key1': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [4, 5, 6], 'key3': [7, 8, 9]}
>>> keys = d.keys()
>>> [dict(zip(keys, vals)) for vals in zip(*(d[k] for k in keys))]
[{'key3': 7, 'key2': 4, 'key1': 1},
 {'key3': 8, 'key2': 5, 'key1': 2},
 {'key3': 9, 'key2': 6, 'key1': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Chaudhary's answer, I developed a generator-based solution. This might be helpful when the dict is huge.

```
def zip_dict(d):
    for vals in zip(*(d.values())):
        yield dict(zip(d.keys(), vals))
```

Example usage:

```
d = dict(
    x=[1,3,5,7,9],
    y=[2,4,6,8,10]
)

for t in zip_dict(d):
    print(t)
```

The result would be:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
{'x': 3, 'y': 4}
{'x': 5, 'y': 6}
{'x': 7, 'y': 8}
{'x': 9, 'y': 10}
```